# R error in data frame : Unexpected end of document when adding new column

Tags: r

I made data frame containing date this way:

```
DD<-seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "day", length.out =31)
DD2 <- data.frame("Date"=DD, var = c(1:31))

DD2<-DD2
```

Now I tried to add a 3rd column but compiler starts raising error msg when I tried to add by mutate a 3rd column into it:

```
DD2<-DD2%>% //Unexpected end of document 
  mutate(Date2=Date%%5)
```

Above code ie reproducible. Why is this error raising ?

Comment: I get `Error in Ops.Date(Date, 5) : %% not defined for "Date" objects`, what do you expect?

Comment: @jay.sf: I am sorry I didn't get your point.

Comment: If you put all your code here, we can detect where the error is. It seems you are using additional and unnecessary pipe operator somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What I get when I run your code I get: "Error in Ops.Date(Date, 5) : %% not defined for "Date" objects", but maybe you're using a library that is OK with the notation (I am just using dplyr).  If you simply run:

```
DD2<-DD2 %>% mutate(Date2=Date-5)
```

it successfully adds the third, mutated column, so the problem is in the %% operation itself.